# Visual Studio 2015 and TFS - All excluded changes being included back automatically

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I was using TFS fine with Visual Studio 2013. I've switched recently to VS 2015 and have an annoying issue (bug ?).

I have a bunch of excluded pending changes that I do not want to commit but that I want to keep locally (bad dev environment, don't ask).
My issue is that everytime I re-open VS 2015, all excluded changes are back into the included changes and I have to manually re-exclude all the stuff I do not want to be committed.

If I open VS 2013, included/excluded changes are still in the perfect state !
Anyone knows what is causing VS 2015 to be such a mess ?

Comment: How many files are there in your excluded list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested this under Visual Studio2015 Update2 and TFS2015 Update3 with about 300 files in excluded list. Everything works prefect.

It's may related to the your VS. First shelveset your excluded list and try to [clear TFS and VS cache.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not/) Then just unshelveset the files and adding them back to excluded list again. If it's still not work, try to uninstall and reinstall your VS.

Comment: I did not go as far as clean up all the cache but you got me in the lead. In my pending changes, I had a bunch of stuff that I could not shelve because files were added but did not exist anymore locally. After cleaning up my workspace, all seems fine. For some unknown reason VS203 was OK with it but not VS 2015. Thanks anyway for your time.

Answer (score -2):

I had this problem with Visual Studio 2013. To fix it, all I did was:

1. Make sure all my intended changes were shelved
2. Undo all pending changes
3. Close Visual Studio
4. Wipe out the TFS cache at C:\Users\**Username**\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team
   Foundation\5.0\Cache (where Username is your Windows login username)
5. Reopen Visual Studio
6. Unshelved my previous changes back to my workspace

Voila! No more extraneous files showing up in my Excluded Changes list!

Comment: Is the negative rating because you tried it and it failed or was it out of principle because the original post was treating an issue resulting after a transition from VS2013 to VS2015? The problem originally described by this post can occur even without transitioning from VS2013 to VS2015! Such a transition isn't the only catalyst to the stated issue. My solution worked for me. In fact, I believe the accepted solution for VS2015 is too drastic because it makes you lose Visual Studio settings. My solution could have saved a lot of extra effort that the currently accepted solution introduces.

Comment: I had the same issue as the OP, this solution did not fix the problem.