# Visual Studio 2013 and TFS - All excluded changes being included back automatically

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I was using TFS fine with Visual Studio 2013. However, recently I have had an annoying issue (bug?).

I have a bunch of excluded pending changes that I do not want to commit but that I want to keep locally (bad DEV environment; don't ask). My issue is that every time I re-open VS 2013, all excluded changes are back into the included changes and I have to manually re-exclude all the stuff I do not want to be committed.

Does anyone know what is causing VS 2013 to be such a mess?

[This question is an adaptation of a similar StackOverflow question for VS2015 ([Visual Studio 2015 and TFS - All excluded changes being included back automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38617656/visual-studio-2015-and-tfs-all-excluded-changes-being-included-back-automatica/45742863#45742863)), but being specific to VS2013 it can potentially be solved differently.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed it. All I did was:

1. Make sure all my intended changes were shelved
2. Undo all pending changes
3. Close Visual Studio
4. Wipe out the TFS cache* at
   C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\5.0\Cache
   (where Username is your Windows login username). The cache includes all the files stored inside said folder; just delete them!
5. Reopen Visual Studio
6. Unshelve my previous changes back to my workspace

Voila! No more extraneous files showing up in my Excluded Changes list!

Comment: I should mention that my VS 2013 solution is non-destructive to your Visual Studio environment settings and extensions, unlike other solutions provided elsewhere. I believe this solution may also be viable for VS 2015 but that's outside the scope of this thread. I would also need someone with that version of Visual Studio installed to test this and confirm that hunch. My solution above would save developers a lot of effort by cutting down on the number of settings and extensions they'd have to manually restore! It did for me!

Comment: This also works for (at least some variations of) the infernal *TF30063: You are not authorized to access xxx.visualstudio.com\DefaultCollection* problem.

Comment: Works for VS 2019 too