# TFS Compare freezes visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2017, compare, tfs-2015

**ISSUE**

While in VS, right-clicking on a file and selecting "Compare" will completely lock up Visual Studio.

The same happens when right-clicking inside the text-area of a file and doing a Compare.

The same happens regardless of file type... I've tried with .js .vb .cs .ascx .css

Attempting to click anything in the UI, including the minimize or close buttons, does absolutely nothing. The buttons don't even highlight to show hover / focus.  The only way to close VS is through Task Manager.

Other staff with the same spec laptop as me, same version of programs, and same VS solution... are able to Compare just fine.

**SPECS**

Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise

Team Foundation Server 2015

Windows 10 Enterprise

16 GB RAM / i7 1.99 GHz processor

**TROUBLESHOOTING**

I've seen some suggestions of disabling "Identify Helpful Extensions" in Options => Text Editor => HTML => Advanced.  No change.

I've restarted the Windows server that TFS is hosted on.

No events are logged in Event Viewer Application or System.

**ADDITIONAL NOTES**

With a solution already open, VS is currently consuming 0 CPU and between 220 MB and 240 MB of memory.  When I attempt to Compare a file with TFS, and TFS immediately becomes frozen, the Memory remains mostly stagnant. Occasionally going up or down a few MB over the course of minutes.

Comment: Hi adam, any update on this? Did my post help to narrow down the issue?

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT  We're doing a huge upgrade next Friday, so I'm a little nervous about clearing TFS and VS cache right in the heat of things.  My plan is to try this fix Monday, April 2nd.  Will report back on if it worked :-)

Comment: OK, any update or new question/issue, feel free to share here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Other staff with the same spec laptop as me, same version of programs,
>   and same VS solution... are able to Compare just fine.

This should be a client side issue, first try to [clear TFS and VS cache](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not/).

- For TFS2015 Clear TFS caches `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\6.0\Cache`

Beside, you could also be able to **change the  Default Visual Studio Diff Tool** . This will narrow down if the freezes visual studio issue is related to build-in compare tool.

[image]

How to change, the detail step please refer this [blog](https://github.com/deadlydog/VS.DiffAllFiles/wiki/How-To-Change-The-Default-Visual-Studio-Diff-Tool-For-TFVC). If  clear cache not work and other tool works well, suggest you re-install your Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

You can try closing Visual Studio and deleting %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\x.0\Cache and /or %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\xx.0 directories and/or opening Developer Command prompt and running devenv.exe /resetSettings and/or deleting HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0 registry entry (of course, it may be a good idea to back up registry entry prior to deletion)

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested clearing the TFS and VS cache may fix the problem but doing so may have some negative side effects.

Before attempting a full TFS and VS cache clear you can clear the folder located at C:\Users{Username}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation{Version}\Cache
This may limit undesired side effects.

See:
[Visual Studio 2013 and TFS - All excluded changes being included back automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45798878/visual-studio-2013-and-tfs-all-excluded-changes-being-included-back-automatica)